# Is there any supplement for improving lung health?

Tags: health

Is there any supplement or natural remedy for improving lung health? i have been a smoker for 15 years and i have been off of it for 3 months. and i am wondering if there is anything that could help with the recovery. (Mostly past all the withdrawal symptoms)

Answer (score 1):

According to this study [Dietary antioxidants and 10-year lung function decline in adults from the ECRHS survey](http://erj.ersjournals.com/content/50/6/1602286) apples, bananas and tomatoes offer a benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you’ve no doubt damaged your lungs. Fortunately, you should be able to heal most of the damage given time and healthy living. Because smoking causes inflammation in the lungs, you might try taking some Omega 3s (clinically effective dose of 2-3 grams) given that they have anti-inflammatory effects along with plenty of other health benefits. You’ll also want to start challenging your lungs. Go for a walk or go for a hike. When those things aren’t challenging anymore, start jogging, try doing sprint intervals. Your lungs didn’t get to where they are overnight, and they won’t heal overnight either. Be consistent and give it time, you’ll improve.